# key SymPy not found for parallel computing

Tags: julia, sympy

Does SymPy.jl work for parallel computing?

```
@everywhere using SymPy
using LinearAlgebra
using SharedArrays, Distributed

julia> xx = Sym[]
julia> @syms x

julia> @sync @distributed for i = 1:3
       xx = [xx, x]
       end
```

Unhandled Task ERROR: On worker 3:
KeyError: key SymPy [24249f21-da20-56a4-8eb1-6a02cf4ae2e6] not found

https://github.com/JuliaPy/SymPy.jl/issues/483

Comment: I seriously doubt if `sympy` is set up for parallel computing.

Answer (score 0):

`Distributed` is for multi-process (as opposed to multi-threaded) parallelism. Think of it as running multiple independent Julia sessions simultaneously. That means you need to declare your imports on all workers - the `@everywhere` macro is your friend here.

```
@everywhere using SymPy
```

will import the package on all workers, which then allows you to use its functionality across all of them in distributed workloads.

Comment: Thanks. I've got the same error with the following code (the complete code I am using is now posted again). This again comes back to the question if sympy.jl can be used for parallel computing. Does adding "@everywhere"  work for you?